# Find user role from DM DiscordJS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm currently working on a bot where I need to go into DM's with a user, answer questions and update roles in the server.

My current problem is that it gives the role fine, but after the user has been given the role, the bot don't update the roles in it's memory.

So after the user has been given the first role, he needs to send a message in the server for the bot to knows his new roles, and I want to avoid that.

Example : Send message in server -> Bot DM's, answers the questions, bot gives role and send second question -> User answers the new question but bot don't see the user's new role.

```js
function restart(msg, member, memberRole1){
    if(msg.content == "!start"){
        msg.author.send("Riddle1" )
        member.roles.add(memberRole1)

    }

}

function test(msg, memberRole,memberRole2,memberRole3,memberRole4, member){
    console.log(client.guilds.cache.get('ServerID').members.cache.get(msg.author.id).roles)
    if (client.guilds.cache.get('ServerID').members.cache.get(msg.author.id).roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Role1')){
    try {
        if(msg.channel.type == 'DM'){
                if(msg.content == 'Answer1'){
                    member.roles.add(memberRole)
                    msg.author.send("Riddle2")
                }
            
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
    }

    else if(client.guilds.cache.get('ServerID').members.cache.get(msg.author.id).roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Role2')){
        try {
            if(msg.channel.type == 'DM'){
                    if(msg.content == 'Answer2'){
                        member.roles.add(memberRole2)
                        msg.author.send("Riddle3")
    
                    }
            }
    
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    else if(client.guilds.cache.get('ServerID').members.cache.get(msg.author.id).roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Role3')){
        try {
            if(msg.channel.type == 'DM'){
                    if(msg.content == 'Answer3'){
                        member.roles.add(memberRole3)
                        msg.author.send("Riddle4")
                    }
            }
    
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    else if(client.guilds.cache.get('ServerID').members.cache.get(msg.author.id).roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Role4')){
        try {
            if(msg.channel.type == 'DM'){
                    if(msg.content == 'Answer4'){
                        member.roles.add(memberRole4)
                    }
            }
    
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}

client.on('messageCreate', (msg) => {

    let server = client.guilds.cache.get('ServerID')
    let memberRole1= server.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "role1")
    let memberRole= server.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "role2")
    let memberRole2= server.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "role3")
    let memberRole3= server.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "role4")
    let memberRole4= server.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "FinalRole")




    let member = server.members.cache.get(msg.author.id)
    restart(msg, member, memberRole1)
    test(msg, memberRole,memberRole2,memberRole3,memberRole4, member)

  }
  
  );
```

I've already tried to use the same function that is used in the IF, but as said, the bot don't update it's infos until the user send a message in the server.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you treating at quiz and each role is just marker for the bot to know which question they are on?

Comment: Basically, yeah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always force-update the member by doing:

```
member.fetch(true);
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=fetch

**I would not recommend doing this *often*, though.** Instead, you should probably do this once per user if you don't know what riddle they're on, and then locally store state of what riddle they're on in an object. For example:

```
const userToRiddleNum = {};
const roleToRiddleNum = {
  role1: 1,
  role2: 2,
  role3: 3,
  'final role': 4,
};

// Later, in test() or 'messageCreate' or what not

if (!(member.user.id in userToRiddleNum)) {
  // Make sure roles are up to date
  await member.fetch(true);
  // Set the user's riddle num to the highest
  // riddle num of all their roles
  userToRiddleNum[member.user.id] = Math.max(
    ...member.roles.cache.map((role) => roleToRiddleNum[role.name] || 0),
  );
}

// Later

userToRiddleNum[member.user.id] // Up to date!

// Now the user solved a riddle:
userToRiddleNum[member.user.id]++
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you use roles as the way to indicate what question the user is on currently, I would recommend doing something *"easier"*, and that is using **[quick.db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quick.db)**

With that, you can just keep track of peoples questions doing for example something like:

```js
db.set(`${message.member.id}.question`, 1);
```

and then just check what question they are in

```js
if(`${message.member.id}.question`) == 1){
      //They are on question 1 do stuff -->
      db.set(`${message.member.id}.question`, 2);
}
```

You can get familiar with **[quick.db documentation](https://quickdb.js.org/overview/docs)** and play around with it.